# How to start drawing in Freeform on macOS?

Tags: ventura, drawing, wacom

I have a problem with starting drawing in Freeform on macOS Ventura. Is this even possible?

I've heard that freeform will land on macOS in the last update Ventura 13.1 (22C65) and I've opened it and tried to recreate the sample image from the official Freeform marketing page with my small drawing tablet, but I can't find an option to begin drawing.

Comment: I don't have access to my M1 at the moment so I can't test, but I am pretty certain that you can only draw using the iPad/iPhone.  See: [Getting Started Freeform on macOS](https://support.apple.com/en-in/guide/freeform/frfm85d6f7b58/mac) and [Draw in a Freeform board on iPad](https://support.apple.com/en-in/guide/ipad/ipadf825a0bd/ipados)

Answer (score 2):

If you select (right mouse click) to add a sketch, it asks you to use your iPad (if you have one), which works.

Even if I use Freeform on my Wacom One tablet (external monitor attached to my mac) I don't get any pencil functionality.

So I assume, no, at the moment (1/2023), it is not possible.